# error unhashable type: 'Series' occurs when running elections_complete_df.query("FIPS.isnull()") code what to do?

Tags: python, arcgis

i am running an python command on Arcgis module for a training and while editing the data file i have renamed files county_fips to FIPS. the code runs fine.
but when running the code elections_complete_df.query("FIPS.isnull()")
it gives unhashable type: 'Series'. how to modify it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNmy7.png)

i am expecting it to return how many null values are there so as to modify data attributes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; it worked out for me:

```
elections_complete_df.query("FIPS != FIPS")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).